# Accessing Exchange account message store

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

I am trying to access the message store of an Exchange account.
 I am using MAPI. The IMsgStore object is initialized using IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore.
The problem is that when using Exchange Cached Mode, the root folder for the 'Inbox' and Sent' is **IPM_SUBTREE**, while for online mesage store it is **Top of Information Store**.
How can I tell if the message store is located online or it is a local file path ?
I would like to be able to tell that from IMsgStore.

And another thing, do I have to supply the MDB_ONLINE to the IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore call if the message store is online?

This is how it looks now:

```
    hRes = lpSession->OpenMsgStore( NULL,
                                    storeEntryID.cb,
                                    (LPENTRYID) storeEntryID.lpb,
                                    &IID_IMsgStore,
                                    /*MDB_ONLINE | */MDB_WRITE,
                                    (LPMDB *)&msgStore);
```

Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

Check the PR_STORE_OFFLINE property (true for OST, false for online online store).

EDIT

Use Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. PR_STORE_OFFLINE property DASL name is

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6632000B
```

Comment: Ok.. But how do you do that? I am using Outlook 2010

Comment: Use Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. PR_STORE_OFFLINE property  DALS name is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6632000B"

Comment: Looks like comments mangle what SO thinks are the links. See the updated answer for the DASL property name.